# What are the most important vulnerabilities must be where professionalism

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, vulnerability, content-security-policy

As we know that the vulnerabilities are many and varied, but what are the vulnerabilities  in most locations and which need to be addressed and the focus on.

Comment: This is way to broad. WAY to broad. WAAAAYYY, would never ever be a good answer, to broad of a question that should not be asked. You should always research your specific theater. What applies to you we can help with. What applies to everyone we can not. A web server is vastly different than a submarine with a screen door.

Answer (score 1):

What needs to be addressed in one place would not need to be addressed in another. That is why an organization needs to conduct a *risk assessment* to determine what is relevant for them.

One cannot say that any one vulnerability is the most important for everyone.